# Is smuggling bad? What could go wrong?

Tags: glitch-2011

I've just been asked to smuggle a package. Should I accept? Will bad things happen to me if I do/don't?

Comment: Wondering if this question should have a `spoiler` tag?

Comment: The government comes and takes your baby.

Comment: I was concerned for a moment because I had never heard of this game before. Very funny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no negative consequences; it is a "mini-quest" like any other.  See the Glitch Strategy page on [Bureaucrats](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Bureaucrat) for more (if still not much) detail.

Comment: I would say that if you're not going anywhere urgently then you should **most definitely** take up the offer. The rewards are very good, and the quest easily doable if your game isn't lagging too badly and you have some spinach with you.

Comment: The only time I was asked to smuggle something I was in the middle of a time-sensitive quest, but I managed to do both, it was fine. I did almost get caught though.